# Edit counting of added rows after deleted it

Tags: javascript, html-table, rows

I have a problem counting row modules. I make 2 modules, Modules 1 and 2. When I delete Module 2, then add another module, instead of adding Module 2 (like it should), it continues counting with Module 3, skipping over the now-deleted Module 2.
This is my code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
.tf{border-bottom:0;}
</style>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
var num=1;
  function addmodule(in_tbl_name)
  {
    var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
var row1 = document.createElement("TR");
// create table cell 1
var td = document.createElement("TD")
td.setAttribute('colspan',5);
td.bgColor="#A7B8D4";
td.innerHTML = "<label style=\"width:570; background-color:#A7B8D4; color:white;\">"+"Module "+num+"</label>";
row1.appendChild(td);
// add to count variable
num = parseInt(num) + 1;
// append row to table
tbody.appendChild(row1);
  }
    var count=1;
  function addRow(in_tbl_name)
  {
var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
// create row
var row = document.createElement("TR");
var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textborder\';\">";
td1.innerHTML=strHtml1 ;
var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"30\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\';\">";
td2.innerHTML=strHtml2;
var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml3 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\';\">";
td3.innerHTML=strHtml3 ;
var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml4 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\';\">";
td4.innerHTML=strHtml4 ;
// append data to row
row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
row.appendChild(td3);
row.appendChild(td4);
// add to count variable
count = parseInt(count) + 1;
// append row to table
tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  function deleterow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if (rowCount==1) {return false;
}
else{
table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}}
</SCRIPT> 
</head>
<body>
<TABLE ID="tbl" width="570" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="st">
<TH WIDTH="400">Content</TH><TH WIDTH="57">CLO</TH><TH WIDTH="57">PLO</TH>        <TH WIDTH="56">Week</TH>
<p align="center">
<input type="button" onClick="addmodule('tbl')" VALUE="Add Module"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tbl')" VALUE="Add Row">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="deleterow('tbl')" VALUE="delete Row">    </p>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the num variable to track the number of modules. Num is incremented each time a new module is added but never decremented. Try adding num--; to the end of the deleterow function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i added at the end of deleterow function but there is another problem in adding it decrements the number like when delete module row 4 then add another one it will appear module row 3 again see my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added num--; at the end of deleterow function but there is another problem appear that it add a wrong number what should be increment see the image for more description.
[image]

Comment: You have some options on how you could fix that. You could have a Delete Row button and add a Delete Module button with a new deletemodule function. Or you could add logic to the deleterow function to detect whether you are currently deleting a row or a module, and only decrement the num variable if you are currently deleting a module.

Comment: The problem is not in deleting but in counting the module row when delete, could you help me because i'm a beginner in javascript coding.

Answer (score 0):

A sensible solution would be to add the class 'module' to the rows which are "modules". Then when you add a module you count the number of "module" rows.

```js
function createRow(content) {
    var new_row = document.createElement('tr'), 
        new_cell = document.createElement('td');

    if (typeof content === 'string') {
      new_cell.innerHTML = content;
    } else {
      new_cell.appendChild(content);
    }
    new_row.appendChild(new_cell);  
    return new_row;
}

function addModule(table_id) {
    var label = document.createElement('label'),
        row,
        table = document.getElementById(table_id),
        tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
        count;
    
    // A lot going on here:
    // We get all the elements with the class "module"
    // and count them - we then drop the leading zero by turning it into an integer.
    count = parseInt(tbody.getElementsByClassName('module').length + 1);
    label.innerText = 'Module ' + count;
    row = createRow(label);
    row.className = 'module';
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    return row;
}

// Handle when the user clicks button
document.getElementById('addModule').onclick = function(){ addModule('tbl'); };
```

```css
#tbl {}

#tbl .module {
    background-color: #A7B8D4;
}

#tbl .module label {
    width: 570px; 
    background-color:#A7B8D4; 
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
    
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p align="center">
    <input type="button" id="addModule" value="Add Module" /> 
</p>
```

Note that for brevity this does not include fallbacks for older browsers which do not support `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Also for brevity I have not included the add / delete row functions.

Comment: You would need to add this code to the bottom of the page since the last line needs to be after the element on the page. Or you can could use `<input type="button" id="addModule" onClick="addModule('tbl')" value="Add Module" /> `. (Stackoverflow snippets don't work with inline javascript)

Comment: Woops - just realised i broke the code when trying to clean it up. Its fixed now.